# Hot to access principalResult of the transformation? [saxonJS]

Tags: xslt, saxon, saxon-js

I migrate from saxon-CE to saxonJS (v1.2.0)

The output of the XSLT transformation need to be captured as an `XML Document object` as it was in saxon-CE:

```js
var xslPath = './*.xsl';
var xsl = Saxon.requestXML(xslPath);
var proc = Saxon.newXSLT20Processor(xsl);
var xmlDoc;
var xmlDocTransformed;
var xmlStr;

xmlDoc = Saxon.parseXML(app.getLoadedMEI());
xmlDocTransformed = proc.transformToDocument(xmlDoc);
```

[image: Content of the variable xmlDocTransformed:]

It tried to apply SaxonJS this way:

```js
var result;
result = SaxonJS.transform({
         stylesheetLocation: "./*.sef.xml",
         sourceLocation: "./*.xml",
         destination: "application"
      });
```

and expected to get a *transformation results object* where I can access the `principalResult` property as described in the [official documentation](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation1.2/index.html#!api/transform) (#destination) and in this [presentation](https://saxonica.github.io/SaxonJS-Tutorial-2021/presentation/partiiiappa.html#ref.SaxonJS_s1_s4).

When running the code I obtain the following:

[image]

There is no problem with transformation itself: when `destination` is set to `replaceBody` it works as expected.

Comment: Try to store e.g. `var opions = { stylesheetLocation: "...", sourceLocation: "", destination: "application" };` and then call `transform(options);`, afterwards `options.principalResult` should have the principal result document.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: However, oprions.principalResult is not the XML Document object but an array with objects (2 for proccessing instructions and 1 for xml itself, in my case).  I can acess XML by e.g. options.principalResult[2].innerHTML. But maybe is there an easier way to get the XML Document object as it was the ouput of transformToDocument(()?

Comment: Do you run Saxon-JS 2 in the browser? Or with Node.js? Or with both? Do you want or need only a principal result as a DOM document? Or any side effects like DOM manipulation of a rendered HTML document in the browser?

Comment: It's saxonJS (v1.2.0) running in the browser. Only need the transformed XML as I pipe it to other engine.

Comment: Please upgrade to SaxonJS 2.3.

Comment: To have the transformation results wrapped in a document node, specify `destination:"document"`.

Comment: I'd very much like to use the latest release saxonJS. However, It's is not compatible with saxon-ee, v9.8.0.12 which I have available in my oXygen, v20.1. As a matter of fact, even the latest version of oXygen still does not support saxon 10 (cf. https://www.oxygenxml.com/doc/versions/24.0/ug-editor/topics/debugging-supported-processors.html).

Comment: Eventually, I need the transformed XML as string. As with saxon-ce with `Saxon.serializeXML(xmlDocTransformed)`

Answer (score 4):

Eventually I solved my task with the following code (Saxon JS 2.3):

```js
var options = {
        stylesheetLocation: xslPath,
        sourceText: inputXmlStr,
        stylesheetParams: params,
        destination: "document"
    };

    var result = SaxonJS.transform(options);
    var transformedXmlStr = SaxonJS.serialize(result.principalResult);
```

The SEF could be produced by `xslt3` [tool](https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/documentation2/index.html#!starting/installing-nodejs).
Note that you might use the alternative command for this (windows 10 power shell):

```
node node_modules/xslt3/xslt3.js "-t" "-xsl:stylesheet.xsl" "-export:stylesheet.sef.json" "-nogo"
```

Comment: Just curious, is `result.principalResult` a single document fragment node that way or still an array of two or more top level nodes?

Comment: Actually, I don't see the difference between the option `{destination: 'document'}` and `{destination: 'application'}`. Both produce #document-fragment (Chrome) and DocumentFragment(3) (Firefox). But when I serialize it I get everything in string and that is what I need.

Maybe worth noting that `principalResult` is no more appended to `options` in v2.3. You get the object out of the transformation. As I actually was expected at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

One way is, of course, to use the `fn:transform` function with "normal" XSLT code:

```js
const xml = `<root>
  <item>a</item>
</root>`;

const xslt = `<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output method="xml"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:next-match/>
    <xsl:comment>Run with {system-property('xsl:product-name')} {system-property('xsl:product-version')} {system-property('Q{http://saxon.sf.net/}platform')}</xsl:comment>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>`;

const resultString = SaxonJS.XPath.evaluate(`transform(map { 'source-node' : parse-xml($xml), 'stylesheet-text' : $xslt, 'delivery-format' : 'serialized' })?output`, null, { params : { 'xml' : xml, 'xslt' : xslt } });

console.log(resultString);
```

```html
<script src="https://martin-honnen.github.io/Saxon-JS-2.3/SaxonJS2.js"></script>
```

Not recommended for performance reason but perhaps a workaround that avoid the hassle of creating an SEF. If you want to create an SEF, note, that the Node.js `xslt3` tool from Saxonica can also do that, you don't need a current version of Saxon EE, just `xslt3 -t -export:my-sheet.sef.json -nogo -xsl:my-sheet.xsl`.

Comment: As commented above, I use saxon v9.8.0.12 for development. And as stated here saxonJS2 is not compatible with this version:
https://www.saxonica.com/saxon-js/index.xml
So it is not about creating of SEFs only.
Or I misunderstood and it is backwards compatible?

Comment: I don't see the relation between Saxon 9.8 (Java?) and Saxon-JS. If you want to run XSLT 3 in the browser then Saxon-JS 2.3 is the current and recommended Saxon-JS release to do that, the code example above is one way to get the transformation result of an XSLT 3 transformation as a string with JavaScript. The comment about using Saxon-JS and `xslt3` for SEF creation/export was just meant as a way out of being tied to an older version of oXygen or Saxon EE and that way, as you said, not being able to use the current Saxon-JS version to run XSLT 3 in the browser but instead rely on 1.2.